# No pressure in car pressure washer

Tags: electrical, water-pump

Sorry, if off-topic.

I have a two year old electric pressure washer.
Model: Bosch aquatek 100 plus.

I use this every week to wash my car. Last week, the motor was making a lot of sound and the water spray pressure was very low.
So, I took it to the service center where they say the end casing and housing is damaged.

Can this happen? The machine was never abused. Also, they say the pressure washer needs to be serviced every six months. In service, they change some oil of the motor. Is this true, I haven't heard of that from anyone else.

Also, there is nothing mentioned about this service in the service-manual.

Regards,
Rohith M

Comment: Never heard about that. Of course it's good for them to service your washer every 6 month. My washer from Kaercher works since 4 years without any service. I mean something is damaged for sure. Let them repair that stuff and use it like before.

Comment: I think the service center guys are playing some dirty tricks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a pressure washer

Comment: @GabrielMongeon: I didn't find any other accounts in stack exchange to ask this. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this can happen. Pumps have a lot of failure modes, and it wouldn't need any abuse to fail after 2 years. I have had one Karcher live 5 years and one just under 2. Usage: washing the car once a month or thereabouts. They are sturdier than most, but expecting a long life out of any pressure washer is optimistic.

I would be confident the service centre guys are being perfectly honest, and unless you have an extended warranty, this is a hardware failure, that you can either fix or replace.

I'd suggest buying a new one. They aren't high cost.

Answer (score 0):

Water and electricity do not mix. The integrity of the machine is a **must**. If it is a budget washer, simply replace it as it is two years old. If it is a more expensive machine then you have to weigh the cost of replacement against a bona-fida repair.

Comment: The particular model which I bought is not in production anymore. The cost of repair is almost near to the newer model. Newer model has a 100W less powered motor. But, I have used the machine carefully. How will the housing and casing get damaged?

Comment: Sometimes, no matter how well a piece of equipment is used, it fails. Even if you read the operation manual, and if applicable, the maintenance manual explicitly, something or other can still go wrong.

Comment: Yes, such things happen.